# Allow dropdown to overflow other components, except the footer

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a flex container with a card in it. The card has a dropdown that is allowed to go over other components. To allow the dropdown to grow over the edge of the card the dropdown was made "absolute", but now it also goes over the footer.

[image: Example]

Reduced code:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
  <div id="page-container" class="flex flex-wrap justify-center sm:justify-start relative">
        <div class="border rounded-lg border-gray-300 p-4 bg-white m-2 flex flex-col">
           <div>
             <div class="flex justify-between">
               <div class="font-semibold text-xl">Card</div>
               <div class="flex items-center cursor-pointer select-none">
                  <div class="inline select-none pr-8 print-hidden">
                     <div class="text-primary"><i class="far fa-code-branch pr-4"></i>Expand</div>
                        <div class="z-10 absolute rounded-b shadow">
                        <div>
                           First item
                        </div>
                         <div>
                           ...
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="min-h-16 py-5 bg-red text-white flex-shrink-0">
      <div class="container mx-auto">
         <div class="h-full flex-wrap flex justify-between content-center text-center">
            <div class="w-full md:w-auto">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/2000x100.png" class="inline-block h-8 ml-4"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make the footer so that is stays underneath the dropdown?

I could use JavaScript for it to determine the lowest point of the dropdown, and move the footer always below that. But maybe there's a better way by changing some CSS.

See this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/transducer/pen/zYpdddX) for a reduced example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add `overflow-y-scroll` to the parent `div` where you have `z-10`

then specify the `max-height` for the dropdown like this `max-h-[90vh]`

and give the footer `z-20`
have a look at https://play.tailwindcss.com/TqJJRKEEkR .

Comment: Thanks for mentioning these interesting Tailwind features I did not know about. It does not yet do completely what I want, I think my question was not clear. The dropdown going underneath the footer is not what I want. What I want is the footer to go lower than the dropdown, so that both the footer and dropdown are visible (the footer being lower than the dropdown). Do you know how to accomplish this?

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers oh I get it now, I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do, I'm not sure if there is a way to achieve that no idea